# Issue regrading displaying top 10 salaries using ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to work out this with out using TOP

I use the following query to display top 10 salaries

```
     SELECT  Salary
     from
     (
       SELECT  Salary, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS 'Salaries'
       FROM User2
     )#emp 

          WHERE Salaries <=10
```

But i am getting the list as 9000,8000,7000,6000,5000,500,4000,3000,2000,10000..

1000 is missing here

What to do i tried by making

```
        WHERE Salaries <10 (but 10000 is not displaying)
```

What's wrong i made can any give me the appropriate one

Comment: does 'salaries' need the quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I see 500 in your list.  If the salaries are not numeric, then a string sort is used.  So it would be 10000, 9000,8000,7000,6000,5000,4000,3000,2000,1000.  You really should change the column datatype, but if you can't you will need to use the convert function e.g. convert(numeric(9,2),Salary).

Also,I think you would be better off using the Rank function - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx since it does what you are trying to do.  Then if you need the top 15, you only need to make that change.

Example:

```
SELECT Salary
FROM
(SELECT Salary
    ,RANK() OVER 
    (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS 'RANK' From User2) Salaries
WHERE
 Salaries.RANK <= 15
```

Comment: +1. Noticing the fact that salary was a string. Priceless! ;)

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Salary 
FROM User2 
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

Comment: Not wrong, but the problem would have remained due to Salary being a string.

Comment: @Wade73: something not explicitly stated in original question, but noted by yourself. I would have to question the schema design decision to make it a string in the first place...!

Comment: I totally agree with you, just wanted to note that the poster really didn't understand the problem they had was more than just getting the top 10.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be over complicating things.

Try the folowing instead.

```
SELECT TOP 10 Salary FROM User2 ORDER BY Salary DESC
```